# Localization and shortcuts

Tags: localization, internationalization

Sometimes we use shortcuts to denote something. For e.g we can write "Customer Reference Number" as "Customer Reference #". Here we used "#" as a short cut to "Number".

## Is this locale sensitive?

## What other shortcuts can you think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely Locale sensitive.
Please be aware that such shortcuts do not exist in some languages, so if you are looking for them because some text is too long to fit the screen, button or something, this simply won't work (translated text won't use shortcut and won't fit).

As for other shortcuts:

- "Info" for "Information"
- "OS" for "Operating System"
- Other technical words like HD, RAM, CPU, etc. – this may or may not be translated depending on the language

Another possibly interesting issue, possibly related are units, which are usually translated:

- kB, MB, GB, etc. could be translated in French, Russian, Greek, ...
- Inches (in) could be presented as for example 15", this depends on Locale as well
- Not very obvious but time units might be shorten in a different way depending on Locale, i.e. "sec." or "s" for "seconds".

I am pretty sure that there are infinite number of examples, people tend to be very innovative...

Comment: And, of course, most locales will have no idea what an inch is in any case. SI units will generally be relatively safe (there's even a set of "square characters" for them for use in ideographic East Asian type: `㎕ ㎜ ㎟ ㎣ ㎨` in the [CJK compatibility range](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3300.pdf) (PDF)). It's also worth bearing in mind that shortened time units will vary more widely by language — German `Sek.`, Greek `s`or `Δλ`, Russian `s`, `с` or `сек` and so on. As Paweł mentions, even filesizes will get translated (French `ko`, Russian `KБ`).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is. But that's what L10N is for. "№" is another possible choice, although outside ASCII.